# Map over array playlists return unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to Map over my playlists  array 
so that every playlist in the array will get displayed

the console.log(playlistsArray)
logs [image]

but

```
  render() {
  const playlistsArray = this.props.playLists
  console.log(playlistsArray)
    return(


{playlistsArray.map((playlist=>    
   <PlayList
                        playLists={this.props.playLists}
                        selectSong={this.selectSong}
                        selectList={this.selectList}
                    />
                  ))}


  )}
```

Returns Unexpected Token.
Why is that?

Comment: You iterate over `playlistsArray` and in each iteration you get `playlist` inside `map` but you're not using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a hell lot of mistakes in your code. This is the correct code. Please check for the differences.

```
render() {
    const playlistsArray = this.props.playLists
    console.log(playlistsArray)
    return (
        playlistsArray.map((playlist) => <PlayList 
            playLists={this.props.playLists}
            selectSong={this.selectSong}
            selectList={this.selectList}
        />)
    )
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you,
I added key={playlist.id} so each playlist has a unique id,
thinking I would get back my 2 hardcoded playlists.
But it gives back the first one twice... 

this is the initialState of the playlist..

const initState = [

  { id:1,
    title:'Play list 1',
    data:[
    
       list of songs with id, title,artist,album
      
    ]
  },
  { id:2,
    title:'Play list 2',
    data:[

     list of songs with id, title,artist,album

    ]
  }
]

Comment: You are actually putting the complete playlists array to the playlists prop of the <Playlist> component by doing **playLists={this.props.playLists}** . Note that this.props.playLists contains the list of all the playlists and not a particular playlist.
I guess what you actually wanna do here is  **playLists={playlist}**

Comment: Thank you! 
That Solved it.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing enclosing bracket for map

change this

```
{playlistsArray.map((playlist=>
```

to this

```
{playlistsArray.map((playlist)=>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a spelling mistake.

It should be `playlistsArray.map(...)` but you are using `playlistArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `{}` from return return statement.

```
render() {
    const playlistsArray = this.props.playLists;
    console.log(playlistsArray);
    return (playlistsArray.map(playlist =>
                <PlayList
                    playLists = { this.props.playLists }
                    selectSong = { this.selectSong }
                    selectList = { this.selectList }
                />)
    );
}
```